I want to start id from the 101 in flutter
CREATE TABLE tblUser(
  userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  userName TEXT NOT NULL,
  userContactNo TEXT NOT NULL,
  userCountryCode TEXT NOT NULL,
  transactionCreatedDate INTEGER NOT NULL
)

this my table and I want to start userid form the 101.
Example
userid   username   userContactNo  userCountryCode  transactionCreateDate
 101      John        75964348           +1             1719895982000
 102      Deni        99894348           +1             1719896408000
.
.
.


Assuming that your table is empty, try this:
update SQLITE_SEQUENCE 
set seq = 101
where name ='tblUser'


Can you explain in detail?

When you create a table the first available id is 1. The SQL statement in my answer will set the  first available id to 101 for table tblUser.
